# How to transfer a question from one SE site to another

Tags: discussion, support, migration

Recently [a question about the Septuagint](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/34815/lxx-translations-of-qahal) came up that seemed worthy, but belonged more on [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) Stackexchange than on History Stackexchange. Before I've come across questions that were transferred from the site they were originally asked on, to a more relevant site (such as [this one](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/34342/how-do-you-estimate-world-population-of-1000-years-ago) from stats to history), and I'm wondering how I can transfer a question like this.

Does this require a certain amount of reputation above what I've got, and if not, what steps can I take to migrate a question?

Comment: Meta.stackexchange is probably a better place for questions like this. Here's a question on this from there: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### When can a question be migrated, and who can migrate it?

Only questions which are less than 60 days old can be migrated; this rule applies also to moderators. Developers are able to bypass this restriction, but they only do so in very, *very* rare cases.

**Any user with 3,000 reputation** can vote to migrate a question to another site via a list of up to five sites, which are most relevant to that site. Simply load the close dialog, select the **off-topic because** close reason, and then select **belongs on another site** in the off-topic reason list. This will present the list of available migration targets.

[image: Getting to the migrate screen]

On Stack Overflow, migration requires a super-majority when closing, which means that it will only be migrated automatically if *four* users vote to migrate it to the same site, on other sites, three votes for the same target suffice.

If you **don't have 3,000 reputation**, the **site isn't in the list** of available migration targets, or the **question got closed without being migrated**, you can flag the question for moderator attention and request that they migrate it for you. Simply explain in the reason which site you want it to be migrated. (Please select *one* site; don't list all possible sites it *could* go to.)

#### Things to consider when migrating questions

- **Don't migrate crap!** Ever. If the question is likely to be closed on the destination site anyway, don't bother migrating it. Just close it normally and advise the OP of the other site in the comments. If they decide to improve the question, then they can go post it over there, or they can edit their question and have it migrated later.
- **Avoid migrating answered questions.** The point of migration is to send the question to a place where it is on-topic and *can* get answered. If the OP already has an answer, then we've already defeated the purpose of migration and the destination site won't have anything to do with the question. Avoid migrating these questions unless they are of extremely good quality and risk deletion on their current site.
- **Don't migrate for the sake of migration.** We only migrate questions because they are *off-topic on the original site*. It is perfectly possible for a question to be on-topic on multiple sites, but that is not a reason to migrate it elsewhere. As a general rule, if someone asks a question *here*, and it's on-topic *here*, it should stay *here*.
- **Be familiar with the destination site.** If you have never even visited the destination site before, read through the FAQ thoroughly and *make sure* the question actually belongs there. Don't look at the name of a site and automatically assume the question can be asked there. Each site has its own rules, and rules vary greatly across sites.
- **If you're not sure, don't migrate it.** Let someone else who *is* sure do that, or ask for opinions from the community in a relevant chat room.

### What causes a migration to be rejected and what happens after?

A migration can be automatically rejected before it even gets migrated if any of the following conditions apply:

- The user is question-banned or suspended on the destination site
- The question does not contain any tags that exist on the destination site (and the destination site isn't a meta site)
- The question is an *exact* duplicate of [another question on the destination site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97632/check-to-make-sure-a-duplicate-does-not-exist-before-migrating/225679#225679)

A question can also be rejected by the target community after it has already been migrated if it gets closed as a reason other than duplicate, or gets deleted (usually by the owner) on the target site. When a question which was already migrated gets rejected, the entire process of the migration is reversed. All the answers are returned to the origin site and undeleted* and are subsequently deleted on the target site.

***Note:** If the question was already deleted on the origin site, migration rejection does *not* cause the question to be undeleted.

This answer has been copied verbatim from [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work).

Comment: "via a list of up to five sites, which are most relevant to that site" - This doesn't apply to beta sites, which History is for now. Only pro tem mods can migrate.